# WiFi adapter not found Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

Using Ubuntu 20.04 for about 5 months now, Today after an update, Wi-Fi dose'nt work after i restarted the computer.

`lscpi` dose'nt list "network controller" in the output

`iwconfig` lists lo, lxcbr0, enp2s0 and states "no wireless extension"  for all of them.

`sudo lshw -class network` outputs 2 *-network both of them are "-- description: Ethernet interface"

`rfkill list all` doesn't output anything

Also i do not have a ethernet cable but i do have the Ubuntu live installation usb.

Update: even after booting from a live Ubuntu USB, still cannot connect to wifi and same error is shown "no wifi adapter found" this has added another layer to the mystery.

Comment: We need to know what your machine is and what wifi adapter is installed.

Comment: @Raffles what is the command to find that?

Comment: Try `dmseg | grep "wlan" `. Also make sure there isn't a hardware switch or `Fn` key which switches the wireless on or off. Make sure your machine isn't in airplane mode.